# How to use VisualStateManager.GoToState() in Grid

Tags: uwp

How do use `GoToState` when the VSM is within a `Grid`?

This code works with an `AdaptiveTrigger` but not with `GoToState`. `GoToState` requires you to input a class inheriting from `Control` but if you pass `MyUserControl` then it just does nothing. Further inspection shows `MyUserControl` has no `VisualStateGroups`, which makes sense as they are defined in the `Grid`

```xml
    <Page
    x:Class="VisualStateManagerTest.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:VisualStateManagerTest"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Page.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="x:String" x:Key="MyTemplate">
            <UserControl x:Name="MyUserControl">
                <Grid x:Name="RootGrid">
                    <Border x:Name="MyBorder">
                        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind}"/>
                    </Border>


                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Wide">
                                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="600"/>
                                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                    <Setter Target="MyBorder.Background" Value="Red"/>
                                </VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                </Grid>
            </UserControl>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Page.Resources>
    
    <Grid>
        <ListView ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MyTemplate}">
            <ListView.Items>
                <x:String>test</x:String>
                <x:String>test1</x:String>
                <x:String>test2</x:String>
            </ListView.Items>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

If you put the VSGs in the root `UserControl` then they show up as belonging to the `UserControl`'s groups, but the properties are not updated:

```xml
    <Page
    x:Class="VisualStateManagerTest.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:VisualStateManagerTest"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Page.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="x:String" x:Key="MyTemplate">
            <UserControl x:Name="MyUserControl">
                <Grid x:Name="RootGrid">
                    <Border x:Name="MyBorder">
                        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind}"/>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>

                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualState x:Name="Wide">
                            <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                                <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="600"/>
                            </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Target="MyBorder.Background" Value="Red"/>
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            </UserControl>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Page.Resources>
    
    <Grid>
        <ListView ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MyTemplate}">
            <ListView.Items>
                <x:String>test</x:String>
                <x:String>test1</x:String>
                <x:String>test2</x:String>
            </ListView.Items>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Comment: Did my reply help you?

Answer (score 0):

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38175647/uwp-visualstates-in-usercontrol) is very similar to your question.

UserControl does not manifest the value of its property in its control template. It is recommended to put the "VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups" in  child elements of UserControl.